# How to programmatically get the Dask-YARN UI url

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am using Dask YARN to create an application like this:

```
spec = skein.ApplicationSpec( ... )
cluster = YarnCluster.from_specification(spec)
client = Client(cluster)
```

ordinarily I'd then run `yarn application -list` from the command line and get the application Tracking-URL which points to the Skein web UI. I would like to programmatically put this url in my logs. I see the Skein provides this through the Application Client object (https://jcrist.github.io/skein/api.html#application-client) but I don't know how to go from a Dask-yarn client and cluster to having a Skein Application Client object.

How do I get the Skein UI url from my desk-yarn client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address of the Skein Web UI can be accessed via:

```
cluster.application_client.ui.address
```